# Getting protocol not supported when using getJSON on Node js on static json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, node.js

In my node js file, I have this code:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "favs.json", function() {
    console.log( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
})
.always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
});
```

And in the server there is a file called `favs.json` in the same directory as the above js file. However when I visit the page, I get the error:

```
Request Failed: error, Protocol not supported.
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: On serverside us fs to read the file not getJSON getJSON is for frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And in the server there is a file called favs.json in the same directory as the above js file.

If the file is located on server, why don't you just read it with [`fs.readFile()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback)?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileContents;
fs.readFile('./favs.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    fileContents = data;
    // ...
});
```

If you really want to get the contents of that file using `XMLHttpRequest`,

1. Make sure it is accessible via an HTTP(S) server in your application.
2. Enter the full URL to the file you want to fetch (ex. `http://localhost/favs.json`.)

Apparently `$.getJSON` uses an unexpected (possibly null) value as the protocol when it's not specified.