# Using xhr2 with just javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to use xhr2, to read through a json file. I've looked up numerous ways to achieve this but none seem to be working. The function below my require statements is the function that I see most often. Ultimately what I wish to achieve is to make an array of objects by reading through multiple json files in order to fill a select order form on a website I am trying to create.

```
var http = require('http');
const ROOT = "./root_html";
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var mime = require('mime');
//var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
var XMLHttpRequestUpload = XMLHttpRequest.XMLHttpRequestUpload;
//create the server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

function readTextFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

//usage:
readTextFile("/civs/specials.json", function(text){
    var data = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(data);
});
```

I continue to get an error and am having an awfully hard time trying to find any information regarding why this error is occurring.

```
C:\cygwin64\home\User\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:205
          throw new NetworkError("Unsupported protocol " + this._url.protocol);
```

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936062/getting-protocol-not-supported-when-using-getjson-on-node-js-on-static-json-file

Comment: It seems you cannot use xmlhttprequest for local files. Can someone confirm is this is correct or not?

Comment: Why use `xhr2` at all (even it isn't required for http requests, you can do that with `http.request()`)? Just use `fs.readFile()`.

Comment: Or (following @mscdex's comment) if it's a JSON file, you could just `require()` it, which will also parse it into an object for you.

Comment: `require()` is synchronous though FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

You may don't have a running server in your local computer. To run the server in the local computer:

(1) Open Terminal
     (2) `cd <designated folder>`
     (3) `http-server`
     (4) Modify the file location related to the "designated folder" in JS file
         ex) "http://localhost:8080/<related folder>/<JSON file>"
     (5) Open another Terminal
     (6) `node <JS file>`

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm i xmlhttprequest`
2. `var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;`
3. `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`

It's work in my code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).